# How can I shrink multiple divs smoothly and sequentially on screen re-size?

Tags: html, css

I've very interesting HTML/responsive-web problem:

I've several `<div>` elements with `inline-block` display proprties:

```
<div id="a"></div>    <div id="b"></div>    <div id="c"></div>
```

Each element has `max-width` of 200px.

When I shrink the page all the elements shrink proportionally however what I need is give `#a` priority to shrink first, then make `#b` shrink and then make `#c` shrink.

How do I do that? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this question? Let me know if my answer below helps, otherwise I can still help you if you provide more details.

Comment: It does help but I didnt try it out yet. My biggest concern is that it's not going to be fluid when resized but will jump at predefined max-width points.

Comment: You want all divs to display on the same line in all screen sizes?

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to scale them smoothly?

Comment: I've currently got them all scaling smoothly together. Working on their individual order now.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I think this does exactly what you want. If you have any questions let me know.

Comment: Wow @Michael_B that is amazing. Thanks for effort you put into it! That is exactly what I'm looking 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use media queries along the path of the shrinking screen size.

For instance, you can start with something like this...

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) { #a { width: 100px; } }
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { #b { width: 100px; } }
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) { #c { width: 100px; } }
```

... and replicate the code at different thresholds with appropriate adjustments for screen size and div width.

---

UPDATE

Thanks for the clarification in your comments. You want to scale down the widths of three divs, with each div scaling down sequentially *and smoothly*. This can be done with a combination of CSS **[media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)** and **[transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)**.

HTML

```
<div id="a">DIV BOX A</div>
<div id="b">DIV BOX B</div>
<div id="c">DIV BOX C</div>
```

CSS

```
div { display: inline-block; width: 200px; }

div { transition: width .5s ease-in-out, left 1s ease-in-out; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) { #a { width: 150px; } } 
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) { #b { width: 150px; } } 
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { #c { width: 150px; } } 

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) { #a { width: 100px; } } 
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) { #b { width: 100px; } } 
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) { #c { width: 100px; } }
```

[**DEMO 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/s7dnghkw/) – `display: inline-block;` based on your code
[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/s7dnghkw/1/) – `display: block;` for demo purposes
<sup>Note: Re-size the window using the vertical bar. Make sure to expand the window all the way to see the full effect.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I like this answer but my concern is that it's not going to be fluid when resized but will jump at predefined max-width points.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries at each of the thresholds where you want each one to shrink should do the trick. Start out with a min-width, and remove it conditionally:

```
/* base rule */

#a, #b, #c {
    min-width:200px;
}

/* conditionally shrink */

@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    #a { min-width:0; }
}
@media all and (max-width: 548px) {
    #b { min-width:0; }
}
@media all and (max-width: 320px) {
    #c { min-width:0; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this answer but my concern is that it's not going to be fluid when resized but will jump at predefined max-width points.

Comment: I just noticed you were using min-width in combination with max-width. Could you explain that?

Comment: The media query evaluates the screen width against the max-width rule - so the rule applies to every screen width below that width. The CSS properties use min-width because it constrains the width to at least that width.